# Crashlytics + OSX app

Tags: macos, crashlytics

I have a problem with crashlytics for my OS X app. Crashlytics integrated without problems.

But in dashboard I have `It looks like we are missing dSYMs to process crashes for the versions below.`

[image]

I used two last variants to export app, but there is no dsym file.

Provision profiles are generated (dist, dev) and downloaded.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. What setting do you have for Debug Information Format on you OS X's app build settings?

Comment: Hi, for Debug Information Format is 'DWARF and dSYM file' for Debug and Release.

Comment: Thanks, that should do the trick unless you are also using Bitcode. Is that enabled?

Comment: Build Settings -> Build options -> NO 'Enable Bitcode' line. 
Does it necessary to add this manually ?

Comment: No need to add that line. Do you have any conditional logic around the run script build phase or have "Run only when installed" on the run script.

Comment: All that I did
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'

and Build Phases
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" {short_key} {long_key}

all steps that Fabric app generated.